# If every ring with characteristic zero contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$, what about the polynomial ring with coefficients in a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I don't really understand the proof for the first part of my question

(1) Every ring with characteristic zero has a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Also, as an example, is the ring of polynomial functions with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ (or with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$), also a ring with characteristic zero? If so, how can I 'see' theorem (1) in action in this case? If it has characteristic non-zero can you give me an example that is not with a ring composed of only numbers?
I am trying to understand this for another proof I have to do for homework but I cannot appreciate this theorem and I have been told that I need it for my problem.

Please be as explicit as possible as I am just starting.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Any ring with unity of characteristic $0$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$ as the subring generated by $1$. Any ring with unity of characteristic $n$ contains $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ as the subring generated by $1$

Comment: The constant polynomials $f(x)=n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ are a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ contained in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: Could you give me an example of such a ring (that is not composed uniquely of numbers like the ring of polynomial functions) to have a more intuitive understanding of what you are saying, please? @user1952009

Comment: @kccu That does not really help me since the constant polynomials $f(x) = n : n \in \mathbb{Z}$, is, in a sense, just $\mathbb{Z}$ (I know I am not being rigurous). I am looking for a ring that is different from a ring of only numbers.

Comment: In a given ring with unity $R$, look at the smallest $n$ such that $\underbrace{1_R+\ldots+1_R}_n = 0_R$. This $n$ is the characteristic of the ring. By convention, if no such $n $ exists, then we say the characteristic is $0$. In that case the subring generated by $1_R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: How about the ring of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$? The identity is the $n \times n$ identity matrix $I_n$, and it generates the subring $\{kI_n : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}k & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots & k \end{bmatrix} : k \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$, which is a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class of admittedly artificial examples, but the copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ is not the obvious one.

Consider your underlying set to be the positive reals, $\mathbb{R}^+$.  Define $a\underline{+} b = ab$ and $a\underline{\cdot} b = 2^{ab}$.  (There is nothing special about $2$ here, any number bigger than $1$ would work fine).

I claim that this defines a field structure on the positive reals.  Rather than verify all the axioms directly, consider the map $\log_2: (\mathbb{R}^+, \underline{+}, \underline{\cdot})\rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$.

Then, note that $$\log_2(a\underline{+}b) = \log_2(ab) = \log_2(a) + \log_2(b)$$ and $$\log_2(a\underline{\cdot}b) = \log_2\left(2^{ab}\right) = a\cdot b.$$

In other words, $\log_2$ is a ring homomorphism.  Because it is clearly bijective, it's an isomorphism, so $(\mathbb{R}^+, \underline{+},\underline{\cdot})$ is a field.

Now, what does the copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ looks like in $\mathbb{R}^+$?  It is the set $\{ 2^z: z\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. In fact, the map $z\mapsto 2^z$ is a ring homomorphism.

$ \ $

More generally, consider a ring $R$ and fix a set $S$ and a bijection $f:R\rightarrow S$.  Then we can put a unique ring structure on $S$ so that $f$ is a ring isomorphism via a process called transport of structure.  For elements $s_1,s_2\in S$, we define $s_1 + s_2:= f(f^{-1}(s_1) + f^{-1}(s_2))$.  Similarly, $s_1s_2:= f(f^{-1}(s_1)f^{-1}(s_2))$.  You can verify that all I did above what transport the field structure on $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$ using the bijection $f(r) = 2^r$.